# Update to head does not undo your local changes?

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

If I have done some local changes to Abc.java and then I go for 'Update to Head' for the same file, it does not undo the changes. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you're using SVN. If so, then that's what it's supposed to do. update will try to merge the changes from the repo to your working copy, so that you may then test your changes with the latest version from the repo, and commit them once you have verified everything is OK.

If you want to undo local changes, you need to do a revert.

Read the SVN book, it's very well written and explains everything clearly: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/

Comment: your answer helped me but I disagree that the svnbook explains it clearly, I checked there first and then came here after it was still unclear to me